# My Ionic Build app not run in android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I create ionic type 1 android application. But while I run it on my android mobile I just found blank white screen. My application is not started and I can't find the error. 
How can I find errors of this application?

[image: This is a screenshot of my application]

Comment: Connect your device with system with usb cable and run chrome://inspect command in url bar in chrome and here you can see app which is running and try to inspect console with some error

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my mobile is not detected in the attached device list.

Answer (score 0):

Check your landing page's .ts file. this usually happens when there is a fatal error and the application fails to run. for simplicity, open cmd to the file;s location and write the following command "ionic serve" this will lunch the application on a browser. then right click on the page and select "inspect element" switch to console and there you have it. this will help you keep track of all the logs before deploying into your phone.
let me know if this answers your question.